# Statistics aggregations in algolia

Tags: algolia

I was looking through the documentation for Algolia and could not find anything related to doing aggregations like you can in elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html

An example of what I want to do is this:

- When a user searches, I show in real time the results of an aggregation on that query as well, such as a count of everything matching a particular filter (e.g. count of all the red items, blue items, yellow items etc)

Answer (score 3):

What ES calls "aggregations" is actually a subset of the "facets" that Algolia provides (see https://www.algolia.com/doc/search/filtering-faceting#faceting). The Algolia faceting capabilities is what you can achieve in ES using the `term` aggregation.

Faceting will compute the counts associated to each faceted value and provides you a way to filter on those values.

Since Algolia has been highly optimized and designed for as-you-type full-text search, the engine doesn't provide deep aggregation capabilities. The only aggregation you would get is the `min`, `max`, `avg` values if the underlying facet values are numbers.

Comment: Ah shit. I want to do date based aggregations. Essentially each user has a list of "availability" slots (a list of `[start_date, end_date]` pairs) and I want to aggregate the number of users who are available in the mornings, afternoons, evenings etc for a particular query (e.g. `{ morning: 100, afternoon: 50, evening: 10 }`)

Comment: Having the counts is built-in with Algolia's faceting; the only thing you will need to reformat is your slots schema. Instead of having `slot: ["08:00", "12:00"]` you could transform that to `slot: "morning"` and just add `slot` to your `attributesForFaceting` and you're done.

Comment: I like it, but the only issue is that it won't work across timezones. I guess a workaround could be to preprocess the data so that I have the availability calculated per timezone. For example, each user has an nested object like the following: `{ morning: [-1, -2], afternoon: [8, 9], ... }` where the numbers are timezones. Then I just take the current users timezone (the user who is searching) and do the aggregation.