# Aggregations in Algolia

Tags: algolia, facet

Is it possible to run the following query in Algolia somehow?

```
SELECT category, avg(numeric_value) as avg_numeric_value
FROM index_name
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY avg_numeric_value DESC
```

This post seems to point to faceting as an option. I read the documentation and tried to make the numeric_value searchable in facets, but with no luck. [Statistics aggregations in algolia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929609/statistics-aggregations-in-algolia)

Answer (score 0):

As I know about Algolia, your query will not work. Because Algolia is not sorting with query results by performance reason. They require you to choose the sort field.

You can do this when you prepare for each record of the category with value about `avg_numberic_value` first and set sorting for this field.